# How to save information from a file in a struct without using a global variable

Tags: c

I have a circuit that is given to me the type name connection+ connection- value in this specific order. My problem is that I have to make a function outside of the main without using global variable and storing the information in a struct. I can make it work but only by using the global variable. Please help me

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include "fileio.h"

#include <string.h>

typedef struct {      
    char tipo, NoM, Nom;    
    char nome[20];    
    float valor;    
}organ;
    
organ circuito[7];  

int leitura(organ *circuito) {        
    FILE* fd;    
    char titulo[25];
    int i = 0;

    printf("Nome do Ficheiro: ");
    scanf("%s", titulo); //leitura do titulo dado pelo utilizador

    fd = fopen(titulo, "r");

    if (fd != NULL) { 
        while (fgetc(fd) != '\n');    
        i = 0;

        while (
            fscanf(fd, "%c\t%s\t%c\t%c\t%f\n",    
                &circuito[i].tipo,
                circuito[i].nome,  
                &circuito[i].NoM,        
                &circuito[i].Nom,
                &circuito[i].valor) != ".END" || ".end") //isto faz ate encontrar .end
        {
            i++;
        }
        fclose(fd);
    }
    else {
        printf("\nErro!");        
        system("cls");        
    }    

    return 0;    
}
```

Comment: Your code is missing the part that actually uses global variable `circuito`, and passes it to function `leitura`. Thus we cannot help you. Please [edit] your question and add missing information.

Comment: sorry, you need to read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) in order to post correctly here.  You could have your mistake out of this code and you are posting what you believe to be the erroneous code.  That includes globals, `#include` files, and `main()` routine to allow to compile and run your exact code.  If we need to supply those things, probably the code will run in our platform while it doesn't in yours.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

IMHO you have passed a reference to your function from `main()` or somewhere else (which is not known, as you didn't post it).  This means the reference can be pointing to a global variable, a local to another function or even a dynamically allocated one.

```
organ global_variable; \

organ global_array_of_7[7];

int main()
{
     organ local_variable;

     organ *dynamically_allocated_variable = malloc(sizeof (organ));

     organ *dynamically_allocated_array_of_7 = calloc(7, sizeof (organ));

     leitura(&global_variable); /* this passes a reference to a global */
     leitura(&global_array[3]); /* this passes the fourth array element */
     leitura(&local_variable); /* this passes a local variable of main() */
     leitura(dynamically_allocated_variable); /* ... */
     leitura(&dynamically_allocated_array_of_7[6]); /* last element of array */
     ...
}
```

in all cases, you pass a reference to the structure, some are global variables but others aren't.  The *addres of* operator (`&`) makes sure you get the access to the variable, independently where it comes from.

What do you exactly mean with a global variable?  Just a variable?